# Elasticsearch how nested object connection to parent document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I want to understand what cost to fetch a parent document with nested document in it.

> Internally, nested objects index each object in the array as a separate hidden document, meaning that each nested object can be queried independently of the others...

I can't find the explanation how nested document relate to it parent in ES document. Do parent document hold `nested ojbect _id`, when we fetch parent, it just find source of nested object via id and replace that object to id in the result?

Comment: Perhaps this link can help https://discuss.elastic.co/t/whats-nested-documents-layout-inside-the-lucene/59944/4

Comment: From the same link, `There is not a field that contains the doc id for the root document. The nested documents are physically located in the Lucene segment next to the root document.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall idea of nested objects is the following - instead of relying on ids for join as [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) approach is doing it utilise the logical organisation of the documents

Each nested object is written just before the parent document:

```
NESTED_DOC11 NESTED_DOC12 PARENT_DOC1 NESTED_DOC21 NESTED_DOC22 PARENT_DOC2
```

this is a smart trick which is utilised all the time to do efficient querying on the nested object without doing heavy lookups by ids.

However, this implies some limitations - for example you couldn't update/delete/add nested document without reindexing the whole "block"

More information on this approach is [there](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)